# Heat transfer coefficient of a mixture

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

If there is a mixture of alcohol and water, is there a way to calculate the heat transfer coefficient?
What about thermal heat capacity?

Comment: Try to have a look at **lever rule** as a first try

Comment: yes and yes.  See Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot